# How to add 5 more numbers to the existing number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add 5 more numbers to the number that the user puts in but it only goes up to 5. For example if I put 2 it should add 5 more numbers to it so the output should look like this 2 3 4 5 6

```
function myFunction() {
  var getDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  var input = document.getElementById("test").value;
  if (!isNaN(input)) {
    parseInt(input);
    for (var i = input; i <= 5; i++) {
      getDiv.innerHTML += i;
    }
  } else {
    getDiv.innerHTML += input + " is not a number!!<br />";
  }
}
```

Comment: *it only goes up to 5* because your loop has limit of 5 `for (var i = input; i <=5; i++)`

Comment: ` for (var i = input; i <=9; i++) ` Do this and check if the number of digits is equal to 5. Once the no. of digits exceeds 5, you need to stop the loop.

Comment: @Asish the thing is as a user i want to put any number for example 30 and output shoud be  31 32 33 34 35

Comment: @attash You can try to store the numbers in an array

Comment: Increment each number,then store that in an array

Comment: FYI: JavaScript and Java are two completely different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, which adds  `input = parseInt(input);` to make `input` a number, and alters your loop to a range of 5.

```js
function myFunction() {
 var getDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
 var input = document.getElementById("test").value;
  if (!isNaN(input)) {
    input = parseInt(input);
    for (var i = input; i < input + 5; i++) {
      getDiv.innerHTML += i + ' ';
    }
  } else {
    getDiv.innerHTML += input + " is not a number!!<br />";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<input id="test"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Click me</button>
```

Comment: i only wanna show more numbers after the users number for example if the user puts 2 output should be 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: @attash; okay, fixed it, `parseInt(input);` doesn't do anything by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop from 0 to 4 both included and add that each time to the input value, note that you should cast the string `input`, so `parseInt(input);` should be `input = parseInt(input);` because if you don't update `input` to a number then it will stay the  same string and adding a number to astring just concatenate it so "30" + 5 = "305" and the loop will run for that number!

```js
function myFunction() {
 var getDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
 var input = document.getElementById("test").value;
  if (!isNaN(input)) {
    input = parseInt(input);
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      getDiv.innerHTML += i + input;
    }
  } else {
    getDiv.innerHTML += input + " is not a number!!<br />";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<input id="test"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction();">Click me</button>
```